# Statically linking Winsock?

Tags: visual-c++, winsock, compilation

I'm using Winsock 1.1 in my project. I include `wsock32.lib` in "Additional Dependencies".

I'm looking at the DLL project using `depends.exe` and notice that the DLL depends on `wsock32.dll`. How can I statically link it so that it doesn't depend on `wsock32.dll`?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you can't. There is no static winsock library, you can only invoke wsock32.dll. Much the same way that you can't statically link to user32 or kernel32. There are things with wsock32.dll internally that are necessarily different on different versions of Windows, and even different service packs on the same versions of Windows, so statically linking would be a bit of a nightmare.

wsock32.dll is present on all versions of Windows that have TCP/IP installed, though, with the same interface, so there wouldn't be any benefit from statically linking anyway.

Comment: Winsock is not always present. If you want to support very old Windows 95 computers, which do not have TCP/IP installed, they also don't have winsock.dll etc. You may still see computers like that in technical or industrial setups, which need to be serviced. I once had to send a full pallet of CDs to destruction because I assumed that the winsock dll was present on all computers.

Comment: While this may be true, it's a rather moot point; if the OS does not have TCP/IP installed, nothing you do with Winsock related to TCP/IP will work whether you're using the DLL or not, unless you're installing your own implementation of TCP/IP.

Comment: If you only use TCP/IP for optional purposes, but the system must be able to run without TCP/IP, too, then it becomes a problem that your application depends on the presence of TCP/IP. Our application was for primary schools, and had worked flawlessly for a long time. Then we added the ability to send/receive information via TCP/IP, and suddenly the support hotline got glowing... the application didn't start because our exe file depended on winsock.dll... we had to scrap all remaining CDs and change the app to load winsock dynamically.

Comment: Good point, I can see where that would be an issue. It still wouldn't provide a benefit to have a statically linked Winsock though, since it would end up trying to use a non-existent TCP/IP stack, which would crash the system. I will update my answer to reflect this, though.